# Prevent nested content to be formated by surrounding css

Tags: html, css

He guys, right now im working on a conversion-page that is supposed to be included on websites of our partners. We're given a certain space inside their websites to promote our product. The space we're offered is of course supposed to be styled with html and css. And this is where it gets a little complicated. Is there a smart way to prevent our stuff inside their html-structures to be formated by their css?

Sure, I could check all affecting formations and just overwrite them with our own css-formations, but this is pretty dirty and not very reliable in terms of possible changes in the future.

How would you handle this? Might iFrame be a valid solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an iframe you can use a special application of the universal reset concept.

```
/* cssreset.com */

#your_company_div * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: baseline;

/* and perhaps some more... */

background: white;
color: black;
}
```

You *may* want to explicitly define the font/family as well, unless you just want to use theirs to make it fit in better.

The idea here is basically that it shouldn't matter anymore what the parent website has defined for CSS styling, your content should look the same basically no matter what, because the * trumps all.

Note that there is the same sorts of downside with using a universal reset, in that you nuke inheritance and will have to do define margins and padding if you want a non-zero value.

This shouldn't be that big of a downside for you as you are not so much designing a whole web site, and thus for a little extra work up front it won't matter how they change their site, your block will stay mostly the same.

Comment: Interesting, had the idea with "*" already in mind, but didn't think it could work. Thanks for the link cssreset.com. I think this will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Iframe then can invoke your page as external in your partners website with your own stand alone style. Else give a hierarchy style to the div and its child elements